# Twisted and txpostgres callback confusion

Tags: python, multithreading, postgresql, twisted, psycopg2

I'm trying to write a simple service using `twisted` and `txpostgres`. The first thing people that connect will need to do is signup, so I figured I'd start by writing a signup function. And I became confused almost immediately.

Here's the code I wrote - I'll explain my confusion after it.

```
from txpostgres        import txpostgres
from twisted.internet  import reactor, protocol, endpoints
from twisted.protocols import basic

# Start by just connecting to my PostgreSQL server.
conn = txpostgres.Connection()
d = conn.connect('dbname=matchmaker user=postgres')

# Ensure my user table exists.
d.addCallback(lambda _: conn.runOperation('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(username text);'))

class PubProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def connectionMade(self):
        print('Connection made.')
        self.factory.clients.add(self)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print('Connection lost.')
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        # Check whether the user already exists or not...
        d.addCallback(lambda _: conn.runQuery('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE username = "{}"'.format(line)))

        # Wait - how do I actually branch based on that?

class PubFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = set()

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return PubProtocol(self)

endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, "tcp:1025").listen(PubFactory())
print('Starting...')
reactor.run()
```

So this starts off not too bad - I connect to my database (it's set to trust localhost so I don't need to provide a password), then I make sure the table is present.

Since I'm just getting started, I'm going to just naïvely interpret any line received as being a request to signup with that line as a username. I realize this is vulnerable to SQL injections right now - remedying that will be my first priority the moment users can actually signup / get rejected on account of the username already being taken.

The issue is, how do I actually branch based on the results of that query? I could add another callback which takes in what's returned by that query, but lambdas are limited to a single expression (no statements), so it seems like I would have to add a function which simply takes in either a `True` or a `False` based on whether the username is taken or not, and then it'll have to actually handle creating the user or raising the exception.

But this sounds like it'll very quickly dissolve into spaghetti code. I'll just have a pile of functions, because every time I want to ever branch, I'm going to have to write another function.

My understanding is that `twisted` is multithreaded. Each time a connection is made, it gets its own thread. Callbacks are used to do stuff on other threads... but what's the point of actually doing it on another thread? There's no message I can send the user until my database has been queried - doing this on yet another thread seems pointless.

How do I branch based on whether the username is already taken or not? How should I actually write this code? Should I be using a single `Defer` object (`d`) and using it both in the global scope as well as in a method, and if not, how should I be handling that?

Answer (score 0):

One point: `twisted` isn't multi-threaded.  It works on a reactor model, where every time your code *would* block on something like IO, it instead uses the `select` system call, which causes the kernel to notify the process once the IO operation is ready.  While doing this, `twisted` moves over to other code that can continue running.  Multiple pieces of code are never actually running at the same time.